# Use datafile at google cloud storage bucket from python script

Tags: python, keras, google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training

Trying to load a datafile, that I have uploaded to my google cloud storage bucket from my python script (its a keras model training job), but keep getting. *IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://mykerasstorage/my_dataset.npy'*. Altought the file is most definetly uploaded to that place. the code Im using to read the dataset is:

```
    training_data = np.load('gs://mykerasstorage/my_dataset.npy')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing to the file in Google Storage (`gs`) from Python.
Python does not have the `gs` protocol and tries to find a file in your current location named that way, ... which does not find.

If you want to run your script in your machine you have to:

- First, save it to a local file (from the GUI or using the [Google Cloud python library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python))
- Run the script referencing the local file np.load('your_local_path_to_file')

Or you could use [colabs](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb#recent=true) that lets you train your model and run tests with gigantic computing resources.

Comment: Not sure what is the "local path" on the google cloud computing platform where the script is running, how can I get that?

Comment: Hi @Tessmus, you can check out this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python) to download a file in your machine. Notice that you can specify the file destination where the file will be downloaded to. This will be the reference of the "local path" where `numpy.load()` will search for the file you just downloaded. Optionally, you may also use the `gsutil cp` command to easily download a file to your local machine.